# get the same class as function member type passed in template arg

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I'm trying to but I have no idea how to (but may be is not possible) catch the same type class when I passing the function member pointer of a derived class as template parameter.

For instance, having this piece of code,

```
class CObject{

public:
    string m_id;

    void setID(const char * id){
        printf("assign id %s\n",id);
        m_id=string(id);
    }

     ~CObject(){}
};


class CDerivedObject:public CObject{
public:
    ~CDerivedObject(){};
};
```

And with this function template,

```
template < typename _R, class _T, typename..._A>
void function_template_test(_R (_T:: *function_type)(_A...) )
{

    printf("ObjectTypeIs: %s\n",typeid( _T).name());
}
```

In the main function I call function_template_test passing function pointer member CDerivedObject::setID,

```
function_template_test(&CDerivedObject::setID);
```

If I compile this code with g++ (my last version is 5.4.0) it prints **7CObject** that it means that _T is type CObject but in the parameter I have passed  **CDerivedObject::setID.** I know that function setID function belongs to CObject, so the compiler gets the type as this way, but...

Is there a possible way to capture the class type I'm passing on template parameter (i.e, that  _T be CDerivedObject) ?

**EDIT 1**

A solution for my problem could be this,

```
template < class _C, class _R, typename _T, typename..._A>
void _function_template_test(_R (_T:: *function_type)(_A...) )
{

    printf("ObjectTypeIs: %s\n",typeid( _C).name());
}

#define function_template_test(cl, fun)\
        _function_template_test<cl>(&cl::fun)
```

And then I call the function as,

```
function_template_test(CDerivedObject,setID);
```

Is a solution but I prefer template instead of macro.

Comment: Not really, compiler (or at least my g++ compiler) it treats as &CObject::setID instead of &CDerivedObject::setID.

Comment: Don't forget to overload your functions for cv-qualified member functions, ref-qualified member functions, and in C++17, noexcept member functions.  Or depending on what you're doing, maybe you can get away with one parameter representing the entire pointer-to-member-function type and just SFINAE it using `std::is_member_function_pointer`.

Comment: Did you try your solution before posting it?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf. Yes. why ? doesn't it compiles?

Comment: @JordiEspada: It compiles but the template parameter `_C` is unrelated to the member function pointer type, which is the same as before.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Err, If I'm not wrong acording my solution and according my compiler, If I call function_template_test(CDerivedObject,setID), the program prints 14CDerivedObject which means that I get the class type (i.e CDerivedObject) I want to catch. _C is that class.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this program:

```
struct Base { void foo() {} };
struct Derived: Base {};

auto main() -> int
{
    int x = &Derived::foo;
}
```

Here's the result of compiling with MinGW g++:

```
[H:\forums\so\056]
> g++ main.cpp
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:23: error: cannot convert 'void (Base::*)()' to 'int' in initialization
     int x = &Derived::foo;
                       ^~~

[H:\forums\so\056]
> _
```

As you can see the type of `&Derived::foo` is `void (Base::*)()` (and yes, that's according to the standard).

I.e., when you ask

> **”** Is there a possible way to capture the class type I'm passing on template parameter

... that's what you're doing.

To make that type `void (Derived::*)()` you need a function declared in `Derived`.

---

For your case of calling a function that takes a member function pointer, you can alternatively specify all the template arguments explicitly. That works because a `void (Base::*)()` converts implicitly to `void (Derived::*)()`. And yes that's counter-intuitive, and constitutes a little loop-hole in the C++ type system, but it's the way the logic works out when you consider what kinds of objects a member function can be called on.

---

Re the loop-hole, here's an example (see ma, no casts!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    stack<int> st;
    for( int const i : {1, 2, 3} ) { st.push( i ); }

    struct Hack: stack<int> { using stack<int>::c; };
    int const n = (st.*&Hack::c).size();
    cout << "That stack contains " << n << " items." << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't what you mean with your example @Cheers and htl. What I'm asking is if there's a way to capture the class type I'm passing into the template. In the example I'm passing CDerivedObject::setID but template it treats as CObject::setID, so _T is CObject instead of CDerivedObject.

Comment: @Jordi: What that means is that you're **passing** a `void (CObject::*)( char const* )`. And the template matching picks up exactly the types you're passing.

Comment: `function_template_test<void, (CDObject*::)(const char*)>(&CDerivedObject::setID);` otherwise.

Comment: @水飲み鳥: Not quite, but in that direction yes. To explicitly specify the types one must specify types for the template parameters, which are `_R`, `_T` and `_A`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf but can't be `_A` deduced in that call? I mean, you have to provide up to the last type argument that cannot be deduced, isn't it?

Comment: @水飲み鳥: Apparently not. But that's just my testing with g++. I don't know why it can't infer the argument type, but I guess it's the conversion that stands in the way.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Thanks so much to take your time in this issue and your explanation :).